# ImportError: No module named mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm using easy_install, and I entered:

```
easy_install mechanize
```

and the last line it returned was:

```
Finished processing dependencies for mechanize
```

Now when I try to:

```
import mechanize
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: check where it installed the package, then if this path is in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Comment: Is the mechanize install location on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes, it said: 
Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
and my python directory is c:\python27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked sys.path in the python shell?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
# Returns a list of directories & .egg files
```

For python to find `mechanize`, it needs to be in one of the places listed on sys.path. If you know where `mechanize` was installed, then you can check directly whether it's on sys.path (I'm not sure how to find out where it was installed automagically).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pathing issue. These are fairly annoying. In my experience the best way to deal with them is to avoid them. You should look into using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/). It will take care of python path issues for you.

Comment: While this works and is a reasonable solution, I would recommend using the system python installation as long as you don't need separate environments.

Comment: I disagree. Virtualenv is a requirement for everything short of introductions to programming. The earlier you learn it and start using it, the better. Your system python should only have pip, ipython and virtualenv installed.